MS Report Builder : Group totals are false due to the join in my dataset
I'm designing a report in Report Builder (with Business Central) and I'm having an issue when working with a temporary table.
I have a dataset of two dataitems. The first dataitem is my production order table. The second data item is a temporary table that I create dynamically when loading the report.
On the report, my production orders are display one after the other and grouped by dates. After each order I display the lines in my temporary tables that are linked to this order. The temporary table is displayed as a tablix in a tablix in report builder.
My issue is when adding a total of the volumes of the orders by date. When an order is linked to more than one line of my temporary table, the total is wrong as seen here in red :
enter image description here
The issue is due to the join between my production order table and my temporary table, but there's no left join or equivalent in report builder to my knowledge.
I tried to change my dataset to have, instead of my dataitem temp inside my dataitem prod order, one dataitem after the other.
This solves my totals issue but with this solution the lines of my temporary table are not printed
enter image description here
Any idea how to make either of these solutions work ?
Thanks
I tried to change my dataset to have, instead of my dataitem temp inside my dataitem prod order, one dataitem after the other like this :
First version :
dataitem(PWS_ProductionOrder; "Production Order")
{
dataitem(TempTable; TempTable)
{
UseTemporary = true;
DataItemLink = "PWS_Document No" = field("No.");
}
}
Second Version
dataitem(PWS_ProductionOrder; "Production Order")
{
    }
    dataitem(TempTable; TempTable)
    {
        UseTemporary = true;
    }

This solves my totals issue but with this solution the lines of my temporary table are not printed
enter image description here
